# Problem assigning values of a While loop in different variables

Tags: python-3.x, function, new-operator

i'm coding a function to my phyton3 program that get the weight of 7 people.

I don't know how i assign these 7 values to different variables, like:

```
a = 0
while(a < 7):
    p = int(input("Seu peso"))
    a = a + 1
```

And after that, he assign the different "p" values to different variables like, p1, p2, p3 ...

But with my level of "coding", i simply can't do that.

The general purpose of the program is:

1. Get the different weights
2. Say which are the weight above 90kg
3. Do the arithmetic mean of the values.

And these 3 are why i have the need for different variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the weight of 7 people, you can do the following:

```
weights = [] #This is a list
for i in range(7): #This is a for loop
    w = int(input("Seu peso "))
    weights.append(w)
```

To say what weights are above 90kg:

```
for w in weights:
    if w > 90:
        print(w, "Is greater than 90kg")
```

To find the mean:

```
mean = sum(weights)/len(weights)
print("Mean Weight:", mean)
```